# MS Access concurrent users and transactions

Tags: ms-access

I am developing an application that runs on a network.  It needs to contact to database (access database) very very often, which is stored in server.  Around 30 Client computers contact the database almost every 2-3 seconds.
I need to know could there be potential manifest problem in with the application?

Could there will be a problem if database is being updated by one client, at the same time other client contacts it?

Thanks a lot.
With best regards,
Furqan

Comment: Please write a proper title for your question. It should be possible to understand what you are asking about from the title. Also, please don't say "Experts only please". It makes you come off as a jerk :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of Access and use a proper database. Look up transactions from any databases 101 book.

30 client connections every two or three seconds is peanuts.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get you.  Could you recommend any database book you mentioned above?  I have almost built my application.  Will it be possible to change the database now?

Comment: The easiest way to replace Access would be the free MS Sql Server Express. Here are MS information about such a transition. http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/migration-access.aspx For the database book, try Fundamentals of Database Systems by Elmasri and Navathe. It's a standard college textbook.

Comment: 30 users is perfectly within the realm of what Jet/ACE can support. However, I would say that if that's the starting point, it would probably be a good idea to implement from the ground up with a server database. -1 for the "use a proper database" comment.

Comment: BTW, "30 client connections every two or three seconds" is peanuts for Access/Jet/ACE, too.